# Error when securing Apache server with SSL (certbot error)

Tags: apache, flask, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to deploy my Flask app when using this tutorial:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04.

However, in Step 4 — Obtaining an SSL Certificate, I'm getting an error:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d myapp.com -d www.myapp.com
```

Error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. www.myapp.space (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.myapp.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/yNL6M8LQ0l3pJIqsxge_7aBNrBcbp5lwIvT6Mh1Wbx8 [66.96.162.136]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>\r\n\r\n    <head>\r\n        <title>404 Error - Page Not Found</title>\r\n        <style>\r\n            #ad_frame"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.myapp.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.myapp.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/yNL6M8LQ0l3pJIqsxge_7aBNrBcbp5lwIvT6Mh1Wbx8
   [66.96.162.136]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>\r\n\r\n    <head>\r\n
   <title>404 Error - Page Not Found</title>\r\n        <style>\r\n
   #ad_frame"
```

**mydomain.config in sites-available:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>       
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myapp.com
        ServerAlias www.myapp.com
        ServerAlias *.myapp.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/myapp.wsgi
        <Directory myapp>
            WSGIProcessGroup myapp
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>       
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myapp.com
        ServerAlias www.myapp.com
        ServerAlias *.myapp.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/myapp.wsgi
        <Directory myapp>
            WSGIProcessGroup myapp
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**myapp.wsgi** file in /var/www/html/myapp look like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/myapp')
from frequency_api import app as application
```

AWS EC2 Rules for my app:
[image]

I have bought a domain through domain.com, and I can my API through it using the domain name with HTTP. How can this SSL issue be fixed so I can access through HTTPS? Thanks! Please let me know if there is anything else I should show here.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue and in my case I just turn off the SSL virtual server at port 443. In this case you should delete:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>       
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myapp.com
        ServerAlias www.myapp.com
        ServerAlias *.myapp.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/myapp.wsgi
        <Directory myapp>
            WSGIProcessGroup myapp
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After that, when running `certbot --apache` the SSL virtual host will be setup automatically if you chose the option for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is because the domain you are trying to link with your server is not pointing to your server.

You are trying to issue a certificate for myapp.com for which you need to add dns record of type A for myapp.com pointing towards your ec2 ip.

If you have purchased domain other than myapp.com then you are trying to issue a certificate for wrong domain.

Comment: Hmm ok, would this be in AWS Route53 then? The thing is, I can access both myapp.com and www.myapp.com through http... Yes, my domain is something else than myapp.com:)

Comment: I have added a CNAME set for www.myapp.com pointing to myapp.com..

Comment: What is the domain you purchased from domain.com?

Comment: guitartuner.space. (Misspelled for a second there). I now tried (1) deleting the CNAME and instead (2) adding a type A record set for www.guitartuner.space pointing  toward the same ec2 ip address as guitartuner.space. Did not work, but maybe the change happens slowly?

Comment: So, the problem is you are trying to issue a certificate for myapp.com which belongs to someone else. so What you have to do is you have to replace myapp.com with guitartuner.space and then add A records in your dns with value of your ec2 ip.

Comment: My post came across as pretty confusing, myapp is just a placeholder variable for this stackoverflow post. The actual domain name is guitartuner.space.

Comment: ok then you just have to add dns record type A
goto wherever you added CNAME and add new record
Type A, host @ and value: your ec2 ip

Comment: then delete CNAME record and add A again:
type: A, host: www, value: ec2 instance ip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214090/discussion-between-user10971344-and-afzaal-ahmad).